# how to filter data that pulling from backend in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, filter, angular-material

I have input where I user can search/type a data and I'm wondering how I can make the user ONLY able to search what was already provided from the backend and forbid them from creating new data.

so in my backend I've "Chart" and "Map" words and I figuring out a way to make the user able to search only this. If I user type other than this and press enter, nothing will happen.

Right now, if the user type other text than this two and press enter, it create a new data and push it to the backend.

I don't want to hard code like this (input == "Chart" || input == "Map") since we will be adding more data in the backend later.

super <= data type like "Chart and Map"

```
<div>
<input matInput #input [formControl]="tagCtrl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
[matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes" (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event,null)">
</div>

        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let tag of filteredSuperTags | async" [value]="tag">
                {{tag}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
```

```
  tagCtrl = new FormControl();
  superTags: Tag[] = [];
 filteredSuperTags: Observable<String[]>;
  allsuperTags: Array<Tag> = [];
  allSuperTagNames: Array<String> = new Array<String>();
  add(event: MatChipInputEvent, event1: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
    if (event1 == null) {
      const input = event.input;
      const value = event.value;

      this.tagService.addTag(this._workspace.guid, 'workspace', value).subscribe((tag) => console.log("added", tag));
      this.snackbar.open(input.value + " has been added as super tag.", " ", { duration: 2500 });


      if ((value || '').trim()) { 
        if (this.allSuperTagNames.find((f) => f.toUpperCase() === value.toUpperCase())) 
        {this.superTags.push({ tag: value.trim(), type: TagType.super }); } } 

      // Reset the input value
      if (input) {
        input.value = '';
      }
      this.tagCtrl.setValue(null);
    }
    else {
      const input = event1.option;
      const value = event1.option.value;
      this.tagService.addTag(this._workspace.guid, 'workspace', value).subscribe((tag) => console.log("added", tag));
      this.snackbar.open(input.value + " has been added as super tag.", " ", { duration: 2500 });

      if ((value || '').trim()) { 
        if (this.allSuperTagNames.find((f) => f.toUpperCase() === value.toUpperCase())) 
        {this.superTags.push({ tag: value.trim(), type: TagType.super }); } } 

      if (input) {
        input.value = '';
      }
      this.tagCtrl.setValue(null);
    }

  }
```

any recommendation or help will be really appreciated.

Comment: If its a search than why would you add something? What kind of component are you trying to build?

Comment: Hi..So I want user to be able search from the list and push the selected/typed data to their particular workspace. This is very similar to this (https://stackblitz.com/angular/qdxrokeqakb ) but just like my problem, it seem like you can create other chip beside what was already provide. I'm searching and creating the same chips like stackblitz example In my project but  I want the user to be able to search and add from what was already provided from backend instead giving them ability to create a new one.

Comment: so basically a typeahead that filter the data provided by the backend?

Comment: ahh...It look like it,  just started learning Angular and so never heard about typeahead. but I'm curious, I'll be creating multiple chips and showing the result right beside the user input like the example that I show you so do you know if that is capable of doing that?.. by anychance can you help me implement that? thx

Comment: The example you provided does not allow the selection of something that doesnt already exist, so thats what you need

Comment: oh I mean, if you type other words that are not on the list and press enter, it will create a new chips for you and show you. That's what I don't want. I'm trying to prevent that.

Comment: Remove the add fucntion and it wont create a chip

Comment: but now then user have to click from drop down list after they typed. I still want the user able to type and press Enter if the word are matched tho.

Comment: replace the if under // add our fruit with:     if ((value || '').trim()) {
      if (this.allFruits.find((f) => f.toUpperCase() === value.toUpperCase())) {
          this.fruits.push(value.trim());
      }
    }

Comment: Hi thanks but do you know why it saying "Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Tag'." when I do it like this in my actual code. I"m getting error on value.trim().......      if ((value || '').trim()) { 
        if (this.allSuperTagNames.find((f) => f.toUpperCase() === value.toUpperCase())) 
        { this.superTags.push(value.trim()); } }

Comment: Thats because you cant push a string in an array of tag, use what you had before for the push: this.superTags.push({ tag: value.trim(), type: TagType.super });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your backend was adding the option no matter what because you were calling the service before verifying if the value existed. If its a form, its super weird to call the backend everytime you select something in a typeahead. In my opinion it should be done once when everything is filled properly or on some kind of submit event.

I just moved the service call inside the verification and removed a if that was only used to assign the input and the value but was duplicating about 10 lines. Now you have an if assigning the value and then followed by the content of the previous if.

```
    add(event: MatChipInputEvent, event1: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
        const input = event.input;
        const value = event.value;
        if (event1 === null) {
          input = event.input;
          value = event.value;
        else {
          input = event1.option;
          value = event1.option.value;
        }

        if ((value || '').trim()) { 
            if (this.allSuperTagNames.find((f) => f.toUpperCase() === value.toUpperCase())) 
            {
                this.superTags.push({ tag: value.trim(), type: TagType.super }); 
                this.tagService.addTag(this._workspace.guid, 'workspace', value).subscribe((tag) => console.log("added", tag));
                this.snackbar.open(input.value + " has been added as super tag.", " ", { duration: 2500 });
            } 
         } 

          // Reset the input value
         if (input) {
            input.value = '';
         }
         this.tagCtrl.setValue(null);
      }
```